# Why are changes visible in other branches?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have 2 local and remote branches called master and branch-one.

When I create 3rd branch with updates and commit it, after switching to other branches I can still see new folders and files.

Work flow:

1. git checkout master
2. git branch branch-two
3. git checkout branch-two
4. Add new folders and files
5. git add
6. git commit -m "some message"
7. git push --set-upstream origin branch-two
8. git checkout master

After that I can see locally all the changes and and when I run git status I can see all the files that i can add to stage.

That never happened before, always when I commited changes on other branch, it stays only on that branch.

What could be the reason of that behaviour?

I have restarted VS Code or my PC many times, nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

"I have restarted VS Code or my PC many times, nothing helped." This will not help. Your local and remote git repository are stored on your file system.

I think you need to create a branch from the master branch that do not have the new files and folders. Use the following steps:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git checkout -b branch-two`
3. Make your changes to the state from master.
4. `git add .`
5. `git commit -m "some message"`
6. `git push --set-upstream origin branch-two`

**Do not switch back to master (skip step 8).**

You can see your changes in the branch-two branch. To bring your changes to master (after checking the result on your branch), you can merge them as usual.